# Error: No such device: <UUID of CentOS Live CD>, but live CD isn't connected

Tags: linux, boot, grub2

I've searched far and wide for an answer on this but couldn't find a clear answer, hoping I can get something here - so I ran some `dd` commands to copy data from one device to another within a CentOS Live CD environment. I copied both a boot and root partition to the new device.  But whenever I try to boot from the new device, I get a 'No device found' error along with a UUID that's trying to find.  I then booted from the live CD again to see who the UUID belonged to and found that it belongs to the live CD partition that's on `/dev/dm-0`. My systems is a VMware guest, and I've ensured that I've disconnected all CD rom connections, and made sure to boot from the hard disk, but no dice. I've even checked `grub.cfg` and don't see a reference for that UUID. Any idea on where the Live CD UUID would be referenced during boot?

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: Have you changed `/etc/fstab`?

Comment: thanks for the reply - yes, I checked /etc/fstab, and it has the correct UUID of the both my boot and root directories.  I may just go into rescue mode and retry to installl grub2 again....